# DC Power connector identification

Tags: dc, identification, connector

I've seen this *connector on various rf amplifiers and the like, it's an insulated center pin and a grounded chassis (this one has a tab on the connector)

What is the recommended way to connect to this? I can easily 'make' something work, but I'd rather use it the way it's designed to be used.[image: Bias Tee Power Injector]

*Not the SMA connectors

Comment: It’s not a connector but a feed through capacitor. The intention is to solder a wire to it.

Comment: What does the module specification tell you about that connector. Clearly if it's some cheap s41t off peebay then you won't get an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is not a connector. That is a [feed-through capacitor](https://passive-components.eu/feedthrough-capacitors-technology-and-applications/). The long lead you see coming out of is is simply its terminal. It is intended for soldering to a wire. As it is a "permanent" connection, that is not a connector. Solder a red wire to that lead, and a black wire to the solder lug as the base of the  feed-through capacitor. Then apply the voltage to those two wires, positive on the red wire. (How much voltage, I don't know.)